# react-bootstrap pagination is not working in IE

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap pagination. when the onSelect event has occured getRecents api is called. However, I have a something problem. The pagination is not working only in IE when I click the next button or next page.

plz help me How can I fix it?

Here is my code below.

```
export default class MyPageRecentsContainer extends Component { 
 state = { 
  recents: [], 
  page: 1, 
  numberOfPages: 1, 
} 

componentWillMount = () => { 
  this.getRecents(1) 
}  
getRecents = page => { 
 MyPageActions.getRecents({ 
   page: page, 
   pageSize: 6, 
 }) 
   .then(res => { 
     this.setState({ 
       recents: res.body, 
       ...calculatePagination(res.header), 
     }) 
   }) 
   .catch(err => { 
     alert(err.message) 
   }) 
} 


render() { 
 const { recents, page, numberOfPages, totalCount } = this.state 


 return ( 
   <MyPageRecentsComponent 
     recents={recents} 
     page={page} 
     numberOfPages={numberOfPages} 
     totalCount={totalCount} 
     getRecents={this.getRecents} 
   /> 
 ) 
}
```

this is react container code.
page, numberOfPages, totalCount are transmitted by response headers.

```
import { Pagination } from 'react-bootstrap'
export default class MyPageRecentsComponent extends Component { 
render() { 
  const { 
    recents, 
    page, 
    numberOfPages, 
    totalCount,  

    getRecents,  
  } = this.props  

   return (
       ... 
      {totalCount > 6 ? ( 
        <div className="section__pagination text-center"> 
          <Pagination 
            prev 
            next 
            maxButtons={5} 
            items={numberOfPages} 
            activePage={page} 
            onSelect={newPage => getRecents(newPage)} 
          /> 
        </div> 
      ) : null} 
  ) 
} 
}
```

Comment: which version of IE? If its IE8, make sure you are adding required polyfills to make it work

Comment: I'm using IE 11...

Comment: are you getting any console errors in IE?

Comment: no. I can't get any errors

Comment: The GET method is not working after OPTION method when I click other page